# using printk cause error in embedded linux driver programming

Tags: linux, driver

printk is one of the core debug technique we use in Linux driver development. I have recently experience a weird problem. I read somewhere saying printk can be used in any context. However, when I use printk inside driver "read" function implementation, I see kernel error after it runs for a while. The error message is as following:

```
[  113.017140] cdns-i2c e0005000.i2c: timeout waiting on completion
[  113.023177] edt_ft5426 1-0038: edt_ft5426_ts_read: read error, addr=0x2 len=29.
[  113.030585] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000043
[  113.038688] pgd = c0004000
[  113.041392] [00000043] *pgd=00000000
[  113.044964] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[  113.050872] Modules linked in: bfcore(O)
[  113.054803] CPU: 1 PID: 690 Comm: irq/60-edt-ft54 Tainted: G           O    4.14.0-xilinx #1
[  113.058533] dma_desc_p[MIC_DMA].ready = 0 
[  113.058539] dma_desc_p[SMAP_DMA].ready = 0 
[  113.071478] Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[  113.076004] task: df7e86c0 task.stack: df6f6000
[  113.080535] PC is at irq_finalize_oneshot+0x0/0xf0
[  113.085318] LR is at irq_thread_fn+0x2c/0x34
[  113.089577] pc : [<c0153b00>]    lr : [<c0153c1c>]    psr: 600f0113
[  113.095835] sp : df6f7f48  ip : 00000000  fp : df77751c
[  113.101051] r10: 00000000  r9 : 00000001  r8 : ded48624
[  113.106268] r7 : c0ffffff  r6 : ffffffff  r5 : 00000001  r4 : ffffffff
[  113.112787] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : ffffffff  r0 : ffffffff
[  113.119307] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
[  113.126433] Control: 18c5387d  Table: 1ec0c04a  DAC: 00000051
[  113.132171] Process irq/60-edt-ft54 (pid: 690, stack limit = 0xdf6f6210)
[  113.138862] Stack: (0xdf6f7f48 to 0xdf6f8000)
[  113.143215] 7f40:                   df50b600 ffffe000 ded48600 c0153edc 00000000 c0153d04
[  113.151383] 7f60: 00000000 df777500 df7e4980 df6f6000 00000000 ded48600 c0153d88 df43db70
[  113.159553] 7f80: df77751c c01332c4 df6f6000 df7e4980 c0133194 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  113.167727] 7fa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0106fb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  113.175894] 7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  113.184062] 7fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  113.192243] [<c0153b00>] (irq_finalize_oneshot) from [<c0153d04>] (irq_thread_dtor+0x0/0x7c)
[  113.196794] dma_desc_p[MIC_DMA].ready = 0 
[  113.196799] dma_desc_p[SMAP_DMA].ready = 0 
[  113.208925] [<c0153d04>] (irq_thread_dtor) from [<df6f6000>] (0xdf6f6000)
[  113.215713] Code: 13a00001 e12fff1e e3a00000 e12fff1e (e5903044) 
[  113.221937] ---[ end trace 97dcf8cac1432a55 ]---
[  113.226572] genirq: exiting task "irq/60-edt-ft54" (690) is an active IRQ thread (irq 60)
```

The setup is on a Xilinx Zynq 7020 device. I run a UI program which need touch screen as input device. So I need I2C for that. My driver responsible for reading data from FPGA. After it runs for a while, I got the error. In the log, I have:

```
[  113.196794] dma_desc_p[MIC_DMA].ready = 0 
[  113.196799] dma_desc_p[SMAP_DMA].ready = 0
```

These are generated by my printk statements from the "read" function. If I comment away all the printk statements, the program runs ok. Any idea why there is a conflict between printk and I2C driver?

Comment: It could also be some unrelated bug, for which removing printk happens to rearrange the surrounding code so that the bug is no longer triggered.  For instance, suppose you read from memory that has been freed, and printk is what overwrites that memory with other data.  I think you want to debug the OOPS as you would any other, and if printk is to blame you'll eventually find out.